# jquery undefined global variable

Tags: jquery, global-variables

I have the following:

```
    var ImageArray = [];
    var Images = $('#ImageSelection').children('img');

    var i = 0;

    Images.each(function() {
        var ImageSource = $(this).attr('src');
        var ImageTitle = $(this).attr('alt');
        var ImageHeight;
        getImageDimensions(ImageSource, function(data) {
            ImageHeight = data.height;
            alert(typeof ImageHeight + ' ' + ImageHeight);
        });
        alert(typeof ImageHeight + ' ' + ImageHeight);
        $(this).attr('id', i);
        ImageArray[i] = {
            'src': ImageSource,
            'title': ImageTitle,
            'height': ImageHeight,
            'id': i
        };
        i++;
    });
```

After I run this code, `ImageArray[0].height` is undefined, but the alert in the callback function displays the height just fine, while the alert which is not in the callback, displays undefind.

The getImageDimensions:

```
    function getImageDimensions(path, callback) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            callback({
                height: img.height
            });
        }
        img.src = path;
    }
```

Comment: where u set the ImageArray[] ???

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include that. updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code `var ImageArray = [];` doesn't make `ImageArray` global; quite the contrary! Since you specify `var`, the variable will be local to the scope in which it was defined.

You probably have your code wrapped in `$(document).load(function(){ ... })` which would explain the behavior.

Solution: Get rid of the `var` and assign a value to the variable outside of any `{}`:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">ImageArray = [];</script>
```

Comment: How can I do that with this block of code? How to design it? http://paste.ubuntu.com/977837/

Comment: As I said: Define global variables before `$(document).ready(function() {`

Comment: Now it works, thanks to your solution, and some others' scripts :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be an synchronicity Problem. While querying ImageHeight, the callback hasn't set it. You should set ImageArray[i] in the callback-function.

Following Code should work:

```
    var Images = $('#ImageSelection').children('img');
    var ImageArray = [];
    var i = 0;

    Images.each(function() {

        $(this).attr('id', i);

        getImageDimensions($(this), function(data) {
            var ImageHeight = data.height;
            alert(typeof ImageHeight + ' ' + ImageHeight);

            ImageArray[data.id] = {
                'src': data.src,
                'title': data.title,
                'height': data.height,
                'id': data.id
            };
        });

        i++;

    });

    function getImageDimensions($img, callback) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            callback({
                id: $img.attr('id'),
                height: img.height,
                src: $img.attr('src'),
                title: $img.attr('alt')
            })
        };
        img.src = $img.attr('src');
    };
```

Comment: If I do so, I get undefined for ImageArray

Comment: you have to carry the running-var i into the callback to set the right imageArray-Element

Comment: Im gettings this when calling ImageArray: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of undefined" in refernce to ImageArray[0].src

Comment: The code is still asynchronous, you will have to wait until ImageArray gets _fully_ populated. Querying ImageArray.length e.g. may be misleading, because element 100 could be set before element 0 due to asynchronous behaviour. I will add a new answer with callback if time permits

Answer (score 1):

It's a asynchronism problem.

Try to reproduce your code behaviour. Let's say we have one image in the Images array.

1. Enter the each function body
2. Call the getImageDimension()
3. inside getImageDimension(), create an image, and attach an event handler. That's all: your program goes on.
4. in the each function body, stores the dimension in the ImageArray array. At this point of time, it's still undefined

Somewhere in the near future, the onload callback of your image will be called, and your variable initialized. But it's too late: your each function is already finished.

You need to:

1. create all your images in a loop, and attach your handlers.
2. wait for all of your handler to be triggered (use a counter for example)
3. now that all of your images are displayed, you can select them and get their current height.

Hope it helps !

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I didn't understand, can you please give an example?

Comment: I'v done a bit of refactoring: try it on jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/L57p9/

If it's not clear, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Maybe I'll rearrange my problem. Is there a technique to hold the code, until the callback funciton is executed?

Comment: No, no way: it's the deep nature of Javascript :)

Answer (score 1):

I've refined the code to track image-loading and call processAfterLoading when ready

```
var Images = $('#ImageSelection').children('img');
// new introduced Image-Load-Counter
var ImagesToLoad=Images.length;
var ImageArray = [];
var i = 0;

Images.each(function() {

    $(this).attr('id', i);

    getImageDimensions($(this), function(data) {
        var ImageHeight = data.height;
        alert(typeof ImageHeight + ' ' + ImageHeight);

        ImageArray[data.id] = {
            'src': data.src,
            'title': data.title,
            'height': data.height,
            'id': data.id
        };
        // Keep track of the amount of images to load before working with ImageArray
        ImagesToLoad--;
        if (ImagesToLoad<1) processAfterLoading()
    });

    i++;

});

function getImageDimensions($img, callback) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        callback({
            id: $img.attr('id'),
            height: img.height,
            src: $img.attr('src'),
            title: $img.attr('alt')
        })
    };
    img.src = $img.attr('src');
};

function processAfterLoading() {
    // Do ALL the things with ImageArray
}
```

Comment: This is actually a better technique, which I will adopt now. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var ImageArray = [];
var Images = $('#ImageSelection').children('img');

var i = 0;

Images.each(function() {
    var ImageSource = $(this).attr('src');
    var ImageTitle = $(this).attr('alt');
    var ImageHeight;
    getImageDimensions(ImageSource, function(data) {
        ImageHeight = data.height;
         window.ImageArray[i] = {
        'src': ImageSource,
        'title': ImageTitle,
        'height': ImageHeight,
        'id': i
    };
    });

    $(this).attr('id', i);

    i++;
});
```

Comment: then, I get undefined for ImageArray

Comment: Have you checked it?? imageArray is global u wont get this error.

Comment: I did exactly as you wrote, and when for example I call ImageArray[0].src (first I wait couple of seconds), I get undefined.